# Build boost.locale with icu on OS X

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build boost.locale against a custom ICU build. I have downloaded and built ICU as static libraries in /opt/icu53.1. However, when I try to build boost.locale, it complains that it can't find ICU.

```
./b2 toolset=clang -sICU_PATH=/opt/icu53.1 --with-locale boost.locale.iconv=off boost.locale.icu=on stage 

  Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built
```

I have tried building ICU as dynamic libraries at /opt/icu53.1_dynamic. But, boost doesn't see ICU even with these

```
./b2 toolset=clang -sICU_PATH=/opt/icu53.1dynamic --with-locale boost.locale.iconv=off boost.locale.icu=on stage
 Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built
```

Any ideas on how to get boost to see ICU at the specified location? Thanks

Comment: have you tried the `--reconfigure` option of b2? I think otherwise it caches the "icu : no".

Comment: Hi Arthur, Thanks for commenting. It's been a while since I have tried this (am no longer using ICU in my project). If I get back to trying out boost, I'll give this a try

Answer (score 0):

For me working this lines for Boost 1.64.0:

```
./bootstrap.sh \
    --with-icu=${ICU_DIR} \
    --prefix=${BOOST_PREFIX};

./b2 \
    --prefix=${BOOST_PREFIX} \
    --reconfigure boost.locale.iconv=off boost.locale.icu=on \
    -sICU_PATH=${ICU_DIR};
```

And for Boost 1.74.0:

```
./bootstrap.sh \
    toolset=darwin \
    macosx-version=${VALUE_MACOS_VERSION} \
    macosx-version-min=${VALUE_MACOS_MIN_VERSION} \
    --with-icu=${ICU_DIR};

./b2 \
    toolset=darwin \
    cxxflags="$VALUE_CXXFLAGS" \
    linkflags="$VALUE_LINKFLAGS" \
    optimization=speed \
    --reconfigure boost.locale.iconv=off boost.locale.icu=on \
    --prefix=${BOOST_PREFIX} \
    --stagedir=${BOOST_PREFIX} \
    -sICU_PATH=${ICU_DIR};
```

Beside all of ICU should! be building with the same compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this problem. Boost would not recogonize the ICU libraries, despite having all path and build options (nearly!) correct. The problem came down to incompatible C++ std options. I had the C++ std version set to c++11 for the ICU build, but not set at all for the boost build (and therefore it ended up using a different version). The end result was that boost did not recognize the ICU libraries despite having been provided the correct ICU_PATH. Explicitly setting the c++ library version for both builds fixed it. For example:

```
ICU_PATH="/icu/install/path"

# ICU build
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 ./runConfigureICU MacOSX --prefix="$ICU_PATH"
gnumake -j $(processor_count)
gnumake install

# Boost locale build
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 -sICU_PAth=${ICU_PATH} boost.locale.iconv=off boost.locale.icu=on \ 
      cxxflags=-std=c++11 toolset=clang --with-locale stage
```